# How can I apply model method on records that already exist on server through console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console

The issue that my application is already alive and bunch of user's use data, in which I found bug and fixed it in the code. But how can I modify their data with edited method, which is actually is `before_save` callback?

I have their input for this record stored in another column, I need to modify output.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind if the `updated_at` value of your model changes?

If not, I suppose you could loop through your model collection calling the save method.

```
> Foo.all.each(&:save)
```

If you go this way, you better stop your application before you make changes to the database.